# A trilogy, the first of which was about a girl hiding a flute in a tree stump

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I've been looking for years, trying to figure out if a book I think I read as a kid existed or not. It was a girl (I think a fairy) in a green dress and a blue cape, with dirty blonde hair in thick curls on the cover, and it had something to do with hiding a flute in a tree stump. I have no idea whether or not this is real, but I'm always on google trying to find out the name of the book.

I remember it was in a trilogy, the two other books having one girl in a pink dress with a horse, the other a blue dress with a basket. Do you have any idea what this book could be?

Comment: Do you remember any names from the book? What year did you read it, where did you read it, and when and where do you think it was written?

Comment: This sounds so incredibly familiar to me... like something I read as a child.

Answer (score 15):

#### [*Laurel the Woodfairy*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1889514055)

> When Foxglove the pixie stumbles into the fairy wood, it's Laurel who welcomes him. But she begins to doubt her wisdom when Foxglove disappears-along with the fairies' treasured Crystal. Laurel sets off on a dangerous quest through the Great Forest to find both the pixie and the Crystal. Full color illustrations throughout. Ages 7 and up.

[image: Laurel the Woodfairy front cover]

This was a series of three books, and the publishers also put out two (or so) other series that looked similar visually.

The full set can be found [here](http://www.justmagicdolls.com/meet/jp/StardustClassics/StardustClassics.htm).

Comment: OH MY GOD! thank you! I've been looking for this book for years!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @Maisy- if this is the correct series, would you accept the answer?